# Help needed implementing Bear Upgrade

Tags: prusa-i3, diy-3d-printer

I am attempting to build a 3D printer using the [Bear Upgrade](https://github.com/gregsaun/prusa_i3_b) for guidance.

In this moment, I am implementing the X-Axis. The X_end_idler consist in two parts, the idler and the belt tensioner, as you can see on the following pictures:

[image: X end idler and tensioner]

[image: X end idler]

[image: Belt tensioner]

The belt tensioner is inserted inside the idler. It is attached to the idler with two screws on the back part of the idler.

[image: Back part of the idler]

The tensioner holds a 2GT Idler Pulley as per the image:
 [image: X Idler with tensioner, pulley and belt]

So, here comes my question to anybody that has attempted to implement the Bear Upgrade:

How is the pulley attached to the tensioner?

The tensioner has a hole that crosses from side to side, but there is no space on the design where to fit a screw head nor a nut. I am a bit lost here and would like to know if there is a trick I can follow, before attempting to modify the design.

Here I attach the link to the pieces: [Bear_extruder_and_x_axis](https://github.com/gregsaun/bear_extruder_and_x_axis)

---

Bear_upgrade

Comment: What about a 3 mm axle/shaft, as it is enclosed it will not fall out. You could even cut the head of a screw and use the threads.

Comment: Or maybe a roll/spring-pin?